# How to view Jenkins console output during a build from the terminal after invoking build using curl from the terminal?

Tags: jenkins, curl, terminal, zap

I have built a Jenkins job to run automated ZAP-Proxy scans.

I used `curl -X POST -u YOUR_USER:YOUR_USER_PASSWORD http://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JOB` to build the job from the terminal. Is there a way to display the console output in the terminal while the job is building?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but it's a little more complicated for two reasons:

1. When you trigger a new build via `curl`, then **the build will not *start* immediately**. The build will enter the build queue, and it will only start executing once Jenkins found a suitable executor. Before that time, there is no build URL at all.
2. Technically, the (continuous) **console output is delivered in multiple fragments** that must be retrieved individually via HTTP.

So, once you triggered the build, you need to find its URL *after* if left the build queue. It can be done nicely in Groovy -- as a simpler heuristic, you could just wait for certain time and then use the `lastBuild` reference.

For fetching the console log fragments, you'll use the `<buildUrl>/logText/progressiveText` end point. Create a loop fetching that URL and checking the `X_More_Data` and `X_Text_Size` HTTP headers for information on whether (and what) console output is available. You can do that in `bash` with `curl` in a loop; I found this [Groovy example](https://gist.github.com/t3knoid/77a8903d79ff65194d06a610ec4a6b4b) on the Web.

In the end, the most elegant solution is probably to

- trigger a new build by submitting a Groovy script that will trigger the build *and* then waits for the build to leave the build queue, returning the build URL.
- Then use another script that will poll/fetch/display that build's console output.

If you use the CLI interface for submitting the script, then you can do all those steps in a single script. If you use the REST API, then second part ("continuous output") probably won't work due to output buffering on REST API side.